# Multiple image clicks JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I am having some trouble trying to call a JQuery function from multiple images on my page. if someone could help me out that would be great.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
        <input type="image" name="rateButton[1]" src="img/Rate1.png" height="40" width="40" value="1" onclick="rateBox(1)"/>
        <input type="image" name="rateButton[2]" src="img/Rate2.png" height="40" width="40" value="1" onclick="rateBox(2)"/>
        <input type="image" name="rateButton[3]" src="img/Rate3.png" height="40" width="40" value="1" onclick="rateBox(3)"/>
        <input type="image" name="rateButton[4]" src="img/Rate4.png" height="40" width="40" value="1" onclick="rateBox(4)"/>
        <input type="image" name="rateButton[5]" src="img/Rate5.png"  height="40" width="40" value="1" onclick="rateBox(5)"/>
        <input type="image" name="rateButton[6]" src="img/Rate6.png" height="40" width="40" value="1" onclick="rateBox(6)"/>
        <input type="image" name="rateButton[7]" src="img/Rate7.png" height="40" width="40" value="1" onclick="rateBox(7)"/>
        <input type="image" name="rateButton[8]" src="img/Rate8.png" height="40" width="40" value="1" onclick="rateBox(8)"/>
        <input type="image" name="rateButton[9]" src="img/Rate9.png"  height="40" width="40" value="1" onclick="rateBox(9)"/>
        <input type="image" name="rateButton[10]" src="img/Rate10.png" height="40" width="40" value="1" onclick="rateBox(10)"/><br>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function rateBox(rating){
        // Ajax Call here...
    }
});
```

Comment: You want to call rateBoxn on any image click/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move your function outside the `.ready()` function as others have suggested.

Also the best practice for attaching events to multiple elements is to delegate the event to the parent element. It will attach only one event and listen for events that bubble-up from the selector used. Ex. using JQuery...

```
$(parent-container).on('click', element-selector, function(e){
  // Ajax call here.
});
```

In your situation you can add a parent wrapper (with id = "ratings") and add a class to your rateButtons (class = "rateButton")

reduced DOM for the sake of clarity.

```
<div id="ratings">
    <input type="image" class="rateButton" name="rateButton[1]" src="img/Rate1.png" height="40" width="40" value="1"/>
    <input type="image" class="rateButton" name="rateButton[2]" src="img/Rate2.png" height="40" width="40" value="1"/>
    <input type="image" class="rateButton" name="rateButton[3]" src="img/Rate3.png" height="40" width="40" value="1"/>
    <input type="image" class="rateButton" name="rateButton[4]" src="img/Rate4.png" height="40" width="40" value="1"/>
    <input type="image" class="rateButton" name="rateButton[5]" src="img/Rate5.png"  height="40" width="40" value="1"/>
</div>
<br>
```

and then bind the event on parent (outside the ready function of-course)

```
$('#ratings').on('click', '.rateButton', function(e){
   /* alternatively if the additional parent element is not desired  
      the event can be delegated to the document */

   var elem = this; // to refer to the clicked object
   var index = $(this).index(); // to get the index, this index is 0 based
   alert('clicked element index: '+index);
   // Ajax call here.
});
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bDSGf/)**

[JQuery `.on()` documentaion](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2):

You're defining the function inside jQuery's DOMReady event. This will cause an exception, since the JS engine is already looking for `rateBox()` inside the `window` object. Move it out of the `$(document).ready()` method and you should be fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function rateBox(rating){
    // Ajax Call here...
}
</script>
```

Since the function is being called by a click event on an image, it's inferred that the DOM is already loaded by the time the function is executed anyway, so wrapping it inside the DOMReady is superfluous.

Comment: Ok so if I do a Ajax call outside of the $(document).ready() it will still work?

Comment: Yes. You only need to wrap inside `ready()` when you need to work directly on DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

Move it outside of the document.ready function:

```
function rateBox(rating){
    // Ajax Call here...
}

$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

By defining it outside of document.ready, it is in the scope of `window` and your inline `onclick` events are all in the scope of the `window` object and thus it can be accessed.

You actually can still achieve the `window` scope from the document.ready function if you really wanted to (but there is no reason to):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.rateBox = function(rating){
        // Ajax Call here...
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define rateBox function outside the document.ready function:

```
function rateBox(rating){
    //do it
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Ajax Call here...
});
```